# ConnectionString in LinqToSQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

i wrote a sample with c# but when i use relative connectionstring it doesnt save data to database and doesnt make any exception or error even:

```
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (DataBaseModelDataContext DB = new DataBaseModelDataContext(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"))
    {
        Person person = new Person { Name=NameField.Text,LastName=LastNameField.Text};
        DB.Persons.InsertOnSubmit(person);
        DB.SubmitChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Add successfully");
    }
}
```

but when i change connection string it works:

```
using (DataBaseDataContext DB = new DataBaseDataContext(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Herald\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\LinqToSql\LinqToSql\DataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")
```

but i need to use relative connection string what should i do:

Comment: are you sure you are checking the same database to see where records were added? your two connection strings look both valid but keep in mind the two paths are not the same.

Comment: Your database is probably being overwritten when you build the solution/project.

Comment: Are you *absolutely sure* it isn't saving and then you are over-writing it when you next deploy? What happens if you *immediately* use a new `DataBaseModelDataContext` with the same connection string and fetch the `.Persons` - is it there?

Comment: when it is overwritten,what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get the current directory and map it into the string.

```
path = New Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath;
path = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```

Comment: i think with this solution have extra work,i think there is a simple solution for this!